# Issue with file_picker_cross package in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-dependencies

I'm facing an issue with the file_picker_cross package while working on a Flutter web project.

The error I'm encountering:

```
/C:/Users/ROSE%20PC/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/file_picker_cross-4.6.0/lib/file_picker_cross.dart:136:14: Error: Method not found: 'NullThrownError'.
      throw (NullThrownError());
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have already attempted the following steps to resolve the issue, but they did not work for me:

- Updated the file_picker_cross package to the latest version using flutter pub upgrade file_picker_cross.
- Cleaned the project using flutter clean and reinstalled dependencies with flutter pub get.

Additional information:

- Flutter version: [3.10.1]
- file_picker_cross package version: [4.6.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the package page and repository, it seems abandoned and I find also people opening issues for your same problem [here](https://gitlab.com/TheOneWithTheBraid/file_picker_cross/-/issues/69), the last update of the package was a year ago and so Flutter/Dart version breaking changes might simply break it as well.

I recommend you search for alternatives or to fork and fix the problem from its repository.

Comment: Yes, alternatives packages works for me. thanks